# How is UberEATS maximum delivery distance determined?

Tags: google-maps

How far can the recipient be from the restaurant? Is this quantity determined by Uber or by the restaurant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [UberEATS Restaurant FAQ](https://about.ubereats.com/en/restaurants/faq/), this is worked out by Uber and the restaurant:

> **How far do you deliver?**
>
> This will vary from city to city and depends on courier coverage and customer location. Once you join our platform, we’ll work with you to define the right delivery area for your restaurant.